# Arrays of strings indexed sometime only returns first char by integer

Tags: php, oracle

This bug is driving me nuts
`$sql_build` contains a `SELECT` I have the following loop:

```
$a = 0;
OCIExecute($sql_build);
while(OCIFetch($sql_build))
{
    $ticket_nbr[$a]  = OCIResult($sql_build,"TICKET");
    $date_time[$a]   = OCIResult($sql_build,"DATE_TIME");
    $uid      = OCIResult($sql_build,"ATTUID");
            echo "$uid<BR />";
            echo "$a<BR />";
    $attuid[$a]      = OCIResult($sql_build,"ATTUID");
            echo "$attuid[$a]<BR />";
            $description[$a] = OCIResult($sql_build, "CHANGE_DESC");
            echo "$a|$ticket_nbr[$a]|$date_time[$a]|$attuid[$a]|<br />";;
    $a++;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
jt898u
0
j
0|00000000 |07/13/2012 00:00:00|j|
mt2755
1
m
1|00000000 |07/19/2012 00:00:00|m|
mt2755
2
m
2|00000000 |07/19/2012 16:39:26|m|
jt898u
3
j
3|00000000 |07/19/2012 16:45:53|j|
```

--
so `$ticket_nbr[$a]` do what I expect but `$attuid[$a]` doesn't.

Note  $uid is unused - just a reality check that I get the right value out of the column.

Note: Please don't lecture me on using deprecated functions.

Comment: Do a print_r on your result to see that you're getting all the data you expect from the query.

Comment: You can index the letters of a string *as an* array `$x = 'letters'; $x[3] == 't'`. So most likely the results you expected to be arrays are actually strings.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out $attuid was in the include file and not used as an array. Changed the name and it worked.